# Assigning an object a Vertex Parent through Python script is throwing an error

Tags: python, error

This is an error that only occurs within the script. I can't replicate directly through the UI, which also makes it difficult to try and discern what may be causing it.

The code here is grabbing a vertex (or vertices) from a vertex group and using them to Vertex Parent objects directly onto those positions:

```
    ...
    vgi = box.vertex_groups[handle_pos].index
    vs = [ v for v in box.data.vertices if vgi in [ vg.group for vg in v.groups ] ]
    vertex_index = vs[num].index

    # Load handle from library and add to wall collection
    with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath) as (data_from, data_to):
        data_to.objects = ['Pull']
    handle = data_to.objects[0]
    box.users_collection[0].objects.link(handle)

    # Parent each handle to its corresponding index
    handle.parent = box
    handle.parent_type = 'VERTEX'
    handle.parent_vertices[0] = vertex_index
```

This seems to work... I'm using Vertex Parent because I want the relative parent location but not scale, etc.

The error:

```
ERROR (bke.object): K:\BlenderGit\blender\source\blender\blenkernel\intern\object.c:2380 give_parvert: Evaluated mesh is needed to solve parenting, object position can be wrong now
```

The error sounds like it implies that I should be working with the mesh instead, but these are all commands used on the object. I've tried to update the layer in various places to redraw, but get the same thing.

I can also solve this problem by using Child Constraints, but from a perspective it's much easier to use a parent here. Any ideas on what's causing the error?

Comment: Is _"updating the layer"_  using `context.view_layer.update()` .

Comment: Yes... that's the command I used. I tried it right before the vertex parent command, right after object import, and spot checked a couple other random locations.